# WebLogic com.bea.xml XML validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, weblogic

I am not sure if I implementing this API properly to validate an XML:

```
XmlOptions xmlOp = new XmlOptions();
xmlOp.setDocumentSourceName("C:/Dir/SubDir/SubDir2/myfile.xsd");
assertTrue(doc.validate(xmlOp));
```

I want to validate the xml object `doc` against the schema `File` myfile.xsd.
The assertion is passing but I wanted to make sure that it is passing for the right reason.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently this is the incorrect usage, I passed in the wrong schema and the assertion still passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This WebLogic method does not validate an XML against a schema. The class `Validator` in `javax.xml.validation.Validator` is what I intended to use.